# simulate tail command angularjs

Tags: angularjs, tail

I show a log file in my web page angular. I would like to show this file in real time, so simulate the "tail command linux" on my file.

For the moment I have the following code :

```
$scope.getRPFile = function(logFileId, logType) {
    if(angular.isDefined(timer)) {
        $interval.cancel(timer);
        timer = undefined;
    }

    timer = $interval(function() {
        getRPFileTime(logFileId, logType);
    }, 5000);
};
```

So I reload the file every 5 seconds.

Best solution ?

Comment: Your implemntation is quite ok (as for me) But this is not the question about Angular. This is question about how to get data. So you can check poling, long poling other approaches. You can start from this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology

Comment: You would need to do a Rest service doing the work of extracting the last lines since a given time and sending it back to the AngularJS application. Thus, no need to reload a full log file (which can be several MB in size) on every tick, just fetch the latest lines, append them to you display.